# Reference to Task<> claims it is defined in mscorlib

Tags: c#, ssis, async-await, task-parallel-library, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a working .net 4.5.2 Winforms app which uses OAuth 2.0 and Google DoubleClickBidManager library to make some API calls.

I need to port it to .net 3.5 so that I can package it in SSIS.

The google APIs use Async, Await and Task and to make it work in 3.5, I added [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35) nuget package and fixed a lot reference errors.

But I am unable fix this one:

[image]

Can anyone please give me ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you manage to port the library to 3.5 I would love to see it :)

Comment: First, *What SSIS version*? You *can* use 4.0 in SQL Server 2012+ . Second you can't backport the TPL. The NuGet package adds some classes that look like Task etc, it *doesn't* add the real framework's classes. Google though uses the real Task classes so it can't run on 3.5.

Comment: If you use a SQL Server version before 2012, the only solution is to use the latest Google Api client that was compatible with 3.5 (if any). Or create a command-line tool in 4.5 that will be called by SSIS as an external tool